# 'Public Function' has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, date, vb6-migration

I am having some issue here, and I am not too sure how to handle it. If you could lead me in the right direction, that would be appreciated:

```
Private Function Convert2YearTo4Year(ByVal str_DTG2Year As String) As String

    Dim str_sys4Year As String
    Dim i_sys2Year As Integer
    Dim i_sys2Century As Integer

    str_sys4Year = Right(Str$(Of Date), 4)
    i_sys2Year = Val(Right(str_sys4Year, 2))            'value of system 2-digit yr
    i_sys2Century = Val(Left(str_sys4Year, 2))          'value of system 2-digit century

    If Val(str_DTG2Year) < i_sys2Year And i_sys2Year - Val(str_DTG2Year) > 50 Then         'next century
        Convert2YearTo4Year = Trim$(Str$(i_sys2Century + 1) + str_DTG2Year)
    ElseIf Val(str_DTG2Year) > i_sys2Year And Val(str_DTG2Year) - i_sys2Year > 50 Then     'prev century
        Convert2YearTo4Year = Trim$(Str$(i_sys2Century - 1) + str_DTG2Year)
    Else
        Convert2YearTo4Year = Trim$(Str$(i_sys2Century) + str_DTG2Year)                           'current century
    End If
End Function
```

The error in the title of this post is flagging at **Right(Str$(Of Date), 4)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `Of`.
`Of` is used to pass generic type arguments.

You should replace that whole line with `DateTime.Now.Year`.